# How to add a empty list to the values in a HashMap Java

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

I want to add the keyset and nothing for the values, because they'll be added later after certain conditions are met.

Here's what I currently have:

```java
Map.put(name, null);
```

Is this the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add values to such a map would be to generate the empty list on the fly using [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) instead of worrying about populating the keys apriori:

```java
myMap.computeIfAbsent(someKey, k -> new ArrayList<>).add(someValue);
```